# Linux bash get an input on the same line as execution?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, arguments

I made a .sh file with a program, the current input is as follows:

```
$ ./myprogram.sh
file.txt
```

How can I make it so the input is as follows instead:

```
$ ./myprogram.sh file.txt
```

Comment: Is this string 'file.txt' produced by your script? It it the output of your script? If so then i'm afraid the desired output is imposible,

Answer (score 1):

Inside the shell script, you can refer to the arguments by their positions as `$1`, `$2`, etc. Note that the arguments start at 1, and `$0` is the name of the executed script. `$#` contains the total number of arguments.